# what should I include in Knowledge base to tell prolog that average of 0/0 is zero to avoid zero divisor?

Tags: prolog

this is the facts I entered in the knowledge base and average takes a list and returns the result but when i pose the query

"average([],X)."

it returns X=0 then when i press ; it gives me zero divisor error and I dont understand why,I tried posing the following 4 facts in the KB

average(0,0).

average([],0).

average(0/0,0).

average(0,0/0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you trying to achieve by writing `0/0` (as a matter of fact I'm not sure what any of the facts other than `average([],0).` are there for), but clearly dividing 0 by 0 will cause a division by zero error.

So that's your problem. Remove the occurrences of `0/0` and the error will disappear.

Comment: when I try posing the query average([],X). it returns X=0 which is true but I can still press ; which gives a 0/0 division error .. that is why I tried the writing 0/0 in the knowledge base which did not work..

Comment: @Amrhussein: If `average([], 0).` is the only fact you have and you enter the query `average([], 0).` you most definitely do not get a 0/0 error. That only happens if you have another rule which uses division. I'm guessing that in addition to the 4 facts you said you had, you also have a rule which divides the sum of the given list by the length of the given list? In that case, that's your problem. Because if you do that for the empty list you're dividing 0 (the sum of the empty list) by 0 (the length of the empty list).

Answer (score 1):

what is the code of average/2? 
assuming that the current code is:

```
average(L,X):-
   sumlist(L,Sum),
   length(L,N),
    X is Sum/N.
```

then you should enter the special case like this:

```
average([],0).
average(L,X):-
   sumlist(L,Sum),
   length(L,N),
    X is Sum/N.
```

this will have the behavior you described: "when I try posing the query average([],X). it returns X=0 which is true but I can still press ; which gives a 0/0 division error .. "

to avoid the second error you should prevent prolog from continuing to the second clause if the list is empty.
you can do that either with a cut:

```
average([],0):-!.
average(L,X):-
   sumlist(L,Sum),
   length(L,N),
    X is Sum/N.
```

or by checking the length of the list before dividing

```
average([],0):-!.
average(L,X):-
   sumlist(L,Sum),
   length(L,N),
   N>0,
   X is Sum/N.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on thanosQR's answer (insufficient rep) but you can avoid the cuts by pattern matching:

```
average([], 0).
average([H|T], X):-
    sumlist([H|T], Sum),
    length([H|T], N),
    X is Sum / N.
```

or using the `if -> then ; else` construct:

```
average(L, X):-
    (   L = [] -> 
        X = 0
    ;   sumlist(L, Sum),
        length(L, N),
        X is Sum / N
    ).
```